# Assign attributes to values in array js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In my script, a function uses the values in my teststim array.

```
var teststim =  ["A", "B", "C"]
```

And I want to give 'attributes' to these values, so that for example A has the attribute "name", B "birthday", ...

I need to find a way to have access to these attributes. I thought about something like this:

```
var teststim = {content: "A", attribute: "name"}, 
               {content: "B", attribute: "birthday"}, 
               {content: "C", attribute: "whatever"}
```

Maybe I'm close than I think, but I am not able to access the 'attribute' values corresponding to the content values. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you trying to access the `attribute` properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array of objects:

```
var teststim = [{content: "A", attribute: "name"}, 
                {content: "B", attribute: "birthday"}, 
                {content: "C", attribute: "whatever"}];

for (var i=0; i<teststim.length; i++) {
    var obj = teststim[i];
    if (obj.content=='C') {
        alert(obj.attribute); // "whatever"
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not give properties/attributes to the values of **YOUR** array.
Therefore, you must start with:

```
var arr = [
   {content:'A'},
   {content:'B'},
   {content:'C'}
];
```

Now you can add new attributes, e.g.:

```
arr[0].attribute = '2';
```

Comment: "You can not give properties/attributes to the values of an array." - of course you can.

Comment: What i meant was his array. His array contains strings, thus you can't add properties to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map a value in the array to another (longer?) value, you can use:

```
var mapping = {"A" : "name", 
               "B" : "birthday", 
               "C" : "whatever"}


for(var i = 0, len = teststim.length; i < len; i++)
{
    alert(mapping[teststim[i]]);
}
```

If not, then just have an array of objects:

```
var teststim = [{ 'content' : "A", 'attribute' : "name" }, 
                { 'content' : "B", 'attribute' : "birthday" }, 
                { 'content' : "C", 'attribute' : "whatever" }];


for(var i = 0, len = teststim.length; i < len; i++)
{
    alert(teststim[i].attribute);
}
```